# Is my method throwing me an exception because the proxy is dead?

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

So I've been getting into WebRequests recently and something that I found pretty interesting was making a connection through a proxy.
I looked at some blog posts for some code to get a general idea on how it worked and the most recent one would be this code snippet right here.

```
private static void requestProxy()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://google.com");
            WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("77.121.11.33", 1080);
            myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            request.Proxy = myproxy;
            request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.Print(content);
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I tried making a request using that but it seems that it's throwing me an error everytime I try to use a proxy. However when I am not using a proxy it's not throwing me any errors, so I am assuming that the problem lays within the proxy. I tried using different ones but no go.
What I am doing wrong here and whats going on? How do I make a connection with a proxy properly?

Error message

> System.Net.WebException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.
>   The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIe65.jpg

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Added the error message! Thanks

Comment: Install [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and inspect what is in that response that makes it invalid. As an alternative you could catch that webexception and then read its `Response` stream (assuming it is not null or empty).

Comment: @rene The issue was that I was using a socks proxy, I tried it with a http proxy but now I am getting the error HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request